# Using mysql root account to execute root commands

Tags: penetration-test, linux, sql-injection, mysql

Suppose that I have full root access to mysql databases, but not root user shell (linux). How can I use the full root access to mysql databases to execute root commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the MySQL daemon runs as a non-root user, you can't. At worst, you can exploit a vulnerability in the MySQL daemon and gain a shell running as the same user as MySQL. From there you'd have to use a local privilege escalation vulnerability in the OS to gain root.